# Connect ear and head

Tags: modeling

[image]

I need to connect the mush denser mesh of the ar with the mesh of the head :/

Comment: On a side note, the top of the head probably need more edge loops to be properly shapable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have notice, that connecting a more dense edge loop to an edge loop with less vertices will fail.

[image: different densities in edge loops]

The solution is to use intermediate faces inbetween, translating the vertex count to a higher one and vice versa.

[image: intermediate face]

The resulting quads will subdivide well and work with deformations.

[image: subdivision]

If the area won't deform or is planar (not the case with rounded/concave/convex surfaces), there is no reason not to use triangles.

[image: triangles]

The *topology guides* page has many useful tutorials including [Optimal Edge Flow Loop Reduction](https://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction) featuring this visualization.

[image: edge loop vertex count reduction]

Comment: Thanks for this - wanted a reliable, consistent way to keep the poly-count and distortion low while adding higher-poly detail "add-on" features to my base mesh. Nice site too!